# FCFS simulator I think my pop function is not working?

Tags: c, linked-list, scheduling

Heres my C code.  I am trying to simulate an FCFS scheduler.  By reading in command line arguments  I create a timer to simulate time.  Everytime it increases I check if a process arrived (using the array), if it did I put it into a LinkedList to represent the Ready queue.  Also every time the timer increases, it checks if a process is done, if it is it pops it off the front of the linked list.  This is where my problem lays.  It is incorrectly popping it off.

I am using ./a.out input.dat text.txt 5 0.4 as my test executing.   Heres my input.dat:

```
1 1 10 50

2 2 0 40

3 3 20 50

4 4 7 35

5 5 10 50

6 6 0 40

7 7 20 50

8 9 7 35

9 10 10 50

10 12 0 40
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define n 10
char *cRR;//get the argument for RR time
char *calpha;//get the argument for alpha 
int termination[n];
int full[40];
int arraylength;
int RR;//to hold RR time as an int
int i=0;//used to count amount of numbers in test file
double alpha;//hold alpha time as a double
int at[n];
typedef int LL_pid; // the pid of the PCB
typedef int LL_AT;//the arrival time of the pcb
typedef int LL_priority;//the priority of that PCB
typedef int LL_BT;//the Burst time of that PCB
typedef int LL_termination;
typedef struct LL PCB; //the PCB
struct LL //linked list structure(pcb)
{
    LL_pid pid;
    LL_AT AT;
    LL_priority priority;
    LL_BT BT;
    LL_termination termination;
    PCB *next;//points to next pcb in linked list
};
struct job//used for job queue
{
    int pid2;
    int AT2;
    int priority2;
    int BT2;
};
int LL_length(PCB *pcb_head); //linked list length
void LL_add(PCB **pcb_head,LL_pid ppid, LL_AT AAT, LL_priority ppriority, LL_BT BBT, LL_termination ttermination); //adds PCB to front of list
void LL_pop(PCB **pcb_head); //removes the head from the list & returns its value
void LL_print(PCB **pcb_head); //prints all the processes
void LL_clear(PCB **pcb_head); //deletes all the processes from queue
void LL_append(PCB **pcb_head,LL_pid ppid, LL_AT AAT, LL_priority ppriority, LL_BT BBT,LL_termination ttermination); //adds a process to the end of the list
int LL_elem(PCB **pcb_head, LL_pid d); //checks for the pcb via pid
void add_jobs(int jobss[]); 
struct job jobs[n];//contains all the jobs an array
void find_AT(struct job jobss[],int length);
void fcfs();
void terminationfcfs();
void checktermination(PCB **pcb_head, int i);

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
PCB *pcb_head=NULL;

//*****START COMMAND LINE ARGS
if ( argc != 5 )//if they incorrectly inputed arguments
    {
        /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
        printf( "usage: %s filename, output file name, RR quantum as a int, Alpha value as a float", argv[0] );
    }
    else
    {
        cRR=argv[3];//get arg for RR time
        calpha=argv[4];//get arg for alpha
        alpha=atof(calpha);//convert alpha to float
        RR=atoi(cRR);//convert RR to int


        // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
        FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );//open file which is 2nd arg
        // fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure 
        if ( file == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Could not open file\n" );
} else
        {
        int y=0;//used for while loop below

        while  ( fscanf(file,"%d",&y)!=EOF )//scan file and find all the numbers
            {
              full[i]=y;//insert the numbers into an array
                i++;
            }
            fclose( file );//done using the file
        }
/*TEST PRINTING EVERYTHING IN FILE
int testprint=0;
for(testprint=0;testprint<i;testprint++){printf("%d\n",full[testprint]);}
printf("\nend of array check");*/
//write to file
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen(argv[2], "w+");
   fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");

   fclose(fp);

    }
/////////////////END OF COMMAND ARGUMENT THINGS


add_jobs(full);//adds all inputs from file to the array "jobs"


//START OF FCFS
int timer=0;
int locator = 0;


terminationfcfs();//get all termination times


    for(timer=0;timer<100;timer++){
    printf("Time %d : ", timer);

    checktermination(&pcb_head,timer);      


        for(locator=0;locator<10;locator++){//every second checks each 10 values if it is their term(using linked list) or arrival time using array.
        //IF ARRIVAL TIME ADD TO LINKED LIST THIS IS WORKING 5-25 2:14, same as print, something wrong with check termination
            if (jobs[locator].AT2==timer){
                LL_append(&pcb_head,jobs[locator].pid2,jobs[locator].AT2,jobs[locator].priority2,jobs[locator].BT2,termination[locator]);               
            }

        }
         LL_print(&pcb_head);//this works


    }//END OF FCFS



//LL_print(&pcb_head);
/*test find at

add_jobs(full);

find_AT(jobs,10);
int f=0;
while(f<10){printf("%d ", at[f]); f++;}
*/



/*TEST IF ADD JOBS WORKS)
add_jobs(full);
int f=0;
while(f<10){
printf("%d " , jobs[f].pid2);
printf("%d " , jobs[f].AT2);
printf("%d " , jobs[f].priority2);
printf("%d " , jobs[f].BT2);
printf("\n");
f++;
}*/


/*testing popping array info into linked list
    jobs[0].pid2=5;
    jobs[0].AT2=4;
    jobs[0].priority2=3;
    jobs[0].BT2=2;
    LL_append(&pcb_head, jobs[0].pid2,jobs[0].AT2,jobs[0].priority2,jobs[0].BT2); 
LL_print(&pcb_head);
*/



 /*
    //example usage:
    LL_add(&pcb_head, 7,7,7,7,10); //push value 7 onto stack
    printf("%d\n", pcb_head -> pid); //show stack head value
    LL_add(&pcb_head, 21,21,21,21,31); //push value 21 onto stack
    LL_print(&pcb_head); //print the stack
    if(LL_elem(&pcb_head, 7)) puts("found 7"); //does 7 belong to the stack?
    LL_append(&pcb_head, 0,0,0,0,50); //append 0 to the end of the stack
    LL_print(&pcb_head); //print the stack
    LL_pop(&pcb_head); //pop the stack's head
    LL_print(&pcb_head); //print the stack
    LL_clear(&pcb_head); //clear the stack
    LL_print(&pcb_head); //print the stack
  */
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int LL_length(PCB *pcb_head)
{
    PCB *curr = pcb_head;//set a temp value to the head
    int len = 0;

    while(curr)
    {
        ++len;//increase length variable
        curr = curr -> next;//go to next and keep looping to get whole length
    }
    return len;
}

void LL_add(PCB **pcb_head,LL_pid ppid, LL_AT AAT, LL_priority ppriority, LL_BT BBT, LL_termination ttermination)
{
    PCB *pcb_new = malloc(sizeof(PCB));//allocate memory for another structure (PCB)

    pcb_new -> pid = ppid;//create a pcb with pid inserted
    pcb_new -> AT = AAT;
    pcb_new -> priority = ppriority;
    pcb_new -> BT = BBT;
    pcb_new -> termination = ttermination;
    pcb_new -> next = *pcb_head;//set its next to the head(inserting in front of list)
    *pcb_head = pcb_new;//set the pointer of head to it since it is in front of list now
}

void LL_pop(PCB **pcb_head)
{
PCB *pcb_temp = *pcb_head; 
        printf("Process %d is terminating", pcb_temp->pid);
        *pcb_head = pcb_temp -> next;//get the next in list and set it to head


}



void LL_print(PCB **pcb_head)
{
    PCB *pcb_temp = *pcb_head;

    if(!pcb_temp)
        puts("the list is empty");
    else
    {
      // while(pcb_temp)
       //{
            printf("Process %d is executing...", pcb_temp -> pid);// print all the pids
       // printf("%d ", pcb_temp -> AT);
       // printf("%d ", pcb_temp -> priority);
       // printf("%d ", pcb_temp -> BT);
           //pcb_temp = pcb_temp -> next;//loop to next pcb*/
        //}
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

void LL_clear(PCB **pcb_head)
{
    while(*pcb_head)//this will get every pcb as pop below sets head value to next after deleting it
        LL_pop(pcb_head);
}

void LL_append(PCB **pcb_head,LL_pid ppid, LL_AT AAT, LL_priority ppriority, LL_BT BBT, LL_termination ttermination)
{
    PCB *pcb_temp = *pcb_head;//get head value

    if(!pcb_temp)//if nothing in head value just add the pcb as list is empty
        LL_add(pcb_head, ppid, AAT, ppriority, BBT, ttermination);
    else
    {
        while(pcb_temp -> next)//get the last pcb
            pcb_temp = pcb_temp -> next;

        LL_add(&(pcb_temp -> next), ppid, AAT, ppriority, BBT, ttermination);//add it onto the last
    }
}

void add_jobs(int jobss[]){
int i = 0;
int i2 = 1;
int i3 = 2;
int i4 = 3;
int x =0;
int x2=0;
int x3=0;
int x4=0;
    while(x<10){
    jobs[x].pid2=jobss[i];
    x++;    
    i+=4;
    }

    while(x2<10){
    jobs[x2].AT2=jobss[i2];
    i2+=4;
    x2++;
    }


        while(x3<10){
        jobs[x3].priority2=jobss[i3];
        i3+=4;
        x3++;
        }

        while(x4<10){
        jobs[x4].BT2=jobss[i4];
        i4+=4;
        x4++;
        }
       arraylength=x4;

}

void find_AT(struct job jobss[], int length){
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        if(jobss[i].BT2>0)
        at[i]=jobss[i].AT2;
    }
}



void terminationfcfs(){
//find termination
int h =1;
int storage;
storage= jobs[0].AT2+jobs[0].BT2;
termination[0]=storage;
while(h<10){
    storage=storage+jobs[h].BT2;
    termination[h]=storage;
    h++;
}
}
void checktermination(PCB **pcb_head, int i){
     PCB *pcb_temp = *pcb_head;//get head

                 while(pcb_temp){
                         if(pcb_temp->termination==i)
                         LL_pop(&pcb_temp);
                         else pcb_temp=pcb_temp->next;
                 }
}

int LL_elem(PCB **pcb_head, LL_pid x)
{
    PCB *pcb_temp = *pcb_head;//get head

    while(pcb_temp)
    {
        if(pcb_temp -> pid == x) //set for numbers, modifiable
            return 1;
        else
            pcb_temp = pcb_temp -> next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "incorrectly popping it off".

Comment: Sorry I just updated my code again.  When I pop it off(if the timer is it's termination time) it just keeps printing that it is running, as if it did not pop off.

Comment: The `LL_pop` as written now shouldn't compile, because you are accessing a field member of a non-struct. Use `(*pcb_head)->next`. (`*p->next` is equivalent to `*(p->next)`.) Your pop function probably also should `free` the node memory.

Comment: @iankoo: Yeah, I've seen it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is not with `LL_pop` itself, which is okay, except that you should free the node memory after popping:

```
void LL_pop(PCB **pcb_head)
{
    PCB *pcb_temp = *pcb_head; 

    printf("Process %d is terminating\n", pcb_temp->pid);
    *pcb_head = pcb_temp -> next;
    free(pcb_temp);
}
```

(Remember that each `malloc` should have its corresponding `free`. When pushing allocates, popping should free the allocated resources.)

The error is in the routine that checks for termination, where you call `LL_pop`:

```
LL_pop(&pcb_temp);
```

Here, you pass the address of a local variable. Updating the local pointer will update the iterator pointer, but not the head of the list or any `next` pointers.

Do without the temporary local pointer and iterate with the pointer to pointer passed in as head. This will add one level of indirection. The pointer to pointer should either hold the address of the head pointer for the first node or the address of the `next` pointer for subsequent nodes. It will always hold the address of the pointer to the current node, and will therefore update the correct "incoming" link:

```
void checktermination(PCB **pcb_head, int i)
{
     while (*pcb_head){
         if((*pcb_head)->termination == i) {
             LL_pop(pcb_head);
         } else {
             pcb_head = &(*pcb_head)->next;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why this is written this way? else {
             pcb_head = &(*pcb_head)->next;
         }
sorry I think I need to read up on pointers more, since my background is java..

Comment: You have already used the `&p->next` syntax yourself when you call `LL_add` in `LL_append`: It is the address of the `next` pointer.

Comment: As for `(*pp)->next`: When `pp` is a pointer to a node pointer, i.e. a `PCB **`, you must first dereference it, so hat you get a node pointer, `(*pp)`. You can then access the field of the node pointed to by `(*pp)` with the arrow, as usual. (`*pp->next` is equivalent to `*(pp->next)`, which doesn't work, because `pp` does not point to a struct.)